# Load XLS with ComponentOne C1XLBook and output as PDF?

Tags: excel, pdf, componentone

I would usually use a C1Report to generate my reports which are generated on a server and saved as PDF. In this case the report really needs to be based on an Excel spreadsheet so I am using C1XLBook to build the data in the required format. However, I can't work out how to export this as a PDF file. Possible? The C1 forums seem to be done at the moment so I can't post over there.

Thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

1.Loading a XLS file with C1XLBook :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\mybook.xls");
```

or

```
c1XLBook1.Load(@"c:\mybook.xls");
```

2.Output as PDF:

C1Excel doesn't provide the feature to export to pdf.
see [here](http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/export-excel-to-pdf/#post-609945)
.

However ther is a workaround mentioned [here](http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/export-excel-to-pdf/#post-226219):

```
You may try using the following approach:

1. Load the excel file in FlexGrid.

2. Capture the image of the displayed flexgrid, please refer to the following link that describes the same:

http://our.componentone.com/2011/04/19/control-rendering-in-print-document/

3. Once, you have the image you can save the same to Pdf by using the DrawImage method of c1PDF. Please refer to the following link that describes the same:

http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1pdf/index.html#!XMLDocuments/Reference/html/M_C1_C1Pdf_C1PdfDocument_DrawImage_2_7dee50e8.htm
```